# Validate function not working in ajax form

Tags: 7, ajax, forms

I used Ajax in a form so that submission of form does not lead to reload of the page.It is working . But the problem is **'The Validation code is not working'**. This is the code I have used in the form.

This is the code for submit button.

```
$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'submit_driven_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'myform',
    'method' => 'replace',
    'effect' => 'fade',
  ),
  '#value' => t('Submit'),
);
```

I have put the validation part in the following function.

```
function formname_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  // Validation code
}
```

Am I doing it the wrong way? Should I put the validation part somewhere else?

Comment: Yours function name should be named like this: modulename_formname_validate

Comment: I tried doing that , but it is still not working .

Comment: this is my code                                                                                                                     function ajaxform_ajax_myform_validate($form, &$form_state) {

if (!valid_email_address($form_state['values']['emailid'])) {
    form_set_error('emailid', t("The email address you supplied is not valid."));
  }}

Comment: Try removing the submit callback and see if your validation callbacks now work.  I'm having a similar error where it looks like validation doesn't work but the real problem is that the submit callack gets called regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code.

```
$form['submit']['#validate'] = array('YOUR_VALIDATE_FUNCTION_NAME');
```

Answer (score 1):

I am working with AJAX code nowadays, and as far as I can see, if the form builder is `formname()`, then `formname_validate()` should work as form validation handler.

Comment: should. doesn't.